# Detecting a double-quote-enclosed string with double-quote and backslash escaping, in a Perl Compatible Regular Expression

Tags: regex, pcre

I want to detect a double quote enclosed string with a regular expression.
I did this with a simple: `/"[^"]*"/`
But this doesn't allow for double quotes inside the string, so I would ideally allow double quote by escaping it like `\"`, and of course that would need also allowing `\\` for a single backslash or else a string could never end in a backslash.
How can I accomplish this? ideally with a Perl-compatible regular expression.

PS: No need to escape single quotes and not possible to use them to enclose the string.

Comment: Shouldn't the original simple regexp be: /"[^"]*"/  (Otherwise you can only detect strings which contain exactly one character.)

Comment: @Attilio yes thanks. Any ideas on the solution?

Comment: @Petruza I added the [regex] tag to your question - you could have had this answered in a matter of seconds if you had that tag from the start. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
"(?:\\.|[^"])*"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rY0vO1/1)

For each character in the string, match either a backslash followed by anything, or a character that is not a quote.

And if you need something optimized, here's an alternative:

```
"(?>[^\\"]++|\\.)*+"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rY0vO1/2)

It basically uses possessive quantifiers to avoid backtracking.